# Is there a way to automatically form long MySql INSERT commands based on a C# object's properties?

Tags: c#, mysql

I am converting a program that uses a MongoDB database to use a MySQL database. The database stores information on products and each product is represented in code by a C# object with around fifty properties.
Saving a product object to MongoDb can be done with a single, short line of code. However, to save to MySql I have to create a very lengthy command which is prone to include errors. 
I would like to know whether there is a way to create a MySqlCommand to insert/update an object that automatically takes the parameters from the C# object.

To insert a product into MongoDB, I use this code (simplified for clarity):

```
void SaveProduct( Product p )
{
    IMongoCollection<Product> collection = Db.GetCollection<Product>("products");
    collection.InsertOne(p);
}
```

The exact way that the object is serialised to the database can be controlled by adding attributes to the object's properties.

To insert a product into MySql I use this code:

```
using (MySqlCommand insertCommand = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    insertCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO products("sku, description, categoryid, subcategoryid, [***LOTS MORE VALUE NAMES***] " VALUES (?sku, ?description, ?categoryid, ?subcategoryid), [***LOTS MORE VALUE NAMES***]";
    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?sku", sku);
    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?description", description);
    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?categoryid", categoryid);
    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?subcategoryid", subcategoryid);
    [***LOTS MORE PARAMETERS***]
}
```

As you can see, adding fifty parameters would mean a very long statement which is very prone to error if I omit a parameter or mistype one of the parameter names. This is vastly less convenient than the MongoDb approach.

What I am hoping for is something that forms MySqlCommands by reading the properties of an object, inferring the DB table column names and adding the parameters. Similarly, when reading the database I would like to populate the properties of the object automatically from the line returned by the query.

Comment: Like the Entity Framework?

Comment: PetaPoco or Dapper may be worth a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for sounds like an ORM, and potentially a little more on top like a Mapper.

One well documented approach would be Entity Framework and AutoMapper.

Assuming you have a view or business model like:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Sku { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and an entity like:

```
public partial class Part
{
    public string Sky { get; set; }
    public int PartId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then you would for any properties that line up one to one, just map and call it good. But for types Entity Framework can't infer you'd need to fix the AutoMapper definition:

That would look something like:

```
var mapper = config.CreateMapper<Item, Part>();
mapper.ForMember(dest => dest.PartId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id));
```

And then your actual insert command would look more or less like:

```
 dc.Add(Mapper.Map(srcItem));
```

It **is** more setup work but highly worth it. You also won't have parameter names that can change, and the code compiles without any warning / error.

This is only one example. Dapper is another choice but you throw away a few niceties too to gain performance.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments. I guess I just needed to know what to search for. I think Entity Framework is going to do the job nicely.